# How do I design a wall post with rich content for my Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

Take a look at this wall post that the Nike Fuel app creates for you when you opt to share your run on Facebook -

[image]

I'm trying to build a swim tracking application and I want to build a similarly rich Facebook wall post if users want to share the swim they just recorded. Where do I start off? Went through the documentation briefly but it's so vast and I'm unable to come up with the right search keywords to get my question answered.

The Graph API allows me to post simple text messages as status updates. But I want something better.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I might've stumbled across it - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph